# Jquery mobile 1.4 cordova some samsung android devices fail to trigger swiperight swipeleft events

Tags: android, jquery-mobile, samsung-mobile

cordova 3.6.3-0.2.13
jquerymobile 1.4.4

Betatesting Android, I have here a Samsung S2 android 4.2.2 and a Zopo C2 android 4.2.1 and everything OK (bit slow with refreshing lists and moving sliders, but ok).
iOS no problem.

However with samsung S4 and S5 users report that swipeleft and swiperight on list items doesn't work, well if you really try many times it works, but basically don't.

Did you experienced such behaviour or maybe is just something wrong with my app?

I try changing the `$.event.special.swipe.horizontalDistanceThreshold = 60;` to 30 (default) to 90 also but no improvements.

Can the slider widget interfere with slideleft and slideright somehow?

Any ideas?

Comment: I don't think swipe events are being attached to slider widget upon creating it.

Comment: Ciao Omar, nice to hear from you again. No no no sorry swipe left and swipe right have nothing to do with the slider widged (which is still incredibly buggy on android). Problem here is that some users report that swipeleft and right on <li a> elements are not working as expected, but just on some samsung phones.

Comment: Ciao :) Unfortunately I dont have an Android to test swipe events. Anyway, try removing sliders from page and test swipe events on list items. Maybe mouse/touch events are being colliding in the presence of sliders on the same page.

Comment: Omar, I'm working on a built from scratch slider for not using the widget, and have found that after performing a swipeleft event on the page, the on 'change' events and so the on 'touchmove vmousemove' are not triggered anymore... any ideas how to reset the situation?

Comment: Man, JQM 1.4.0 hasn't this bug! I think I will go back to it.

Comment: Haha, each sub-version has an issue, be careful ;)